# Problems accessing my funds with Ethereum Wallet 0.3.9

Tags: accounts, wallets, mist, contract-debugging

Unfortunately, I have a problem before me. I have on my computer the wallet "Ethereum-Wallet-win64-0-3-9" I have updated recently. On this wallet there is a "contract address" linked to an "account address" in the same wallet that I own. Unfortunately I don't know by which process it took place. I would like to know if there is a solution to get back my 266 ether. Maybe it is possible to re-transfer the ether of "contract address" to "contract creator address". Thank you in advance for your problem. I hope to receive a response from you. Yours

Here is my account Address:[image: account adresse]] Here is my contract address:[image: contract adresse]]

I am the holder of the private key of the contract creator address and the private key of the account address.

What should I do to get my ether?

Comment: Bonjour.  This is an English-language site so please post questions in English.  Merci.

Comment: it will be cool if someone help me :-)

Comment: I put your translations, and submitted a request to reopen the question.  Please check the pictures of the addresses and edit the question since I may have put the pictures wrong.

Comment: can you explain me what i have to do N

Comment: It's ok, looks like I have the pictures correct.

Answer (score 1):

Contracts on Ethereum are autonomous. (Yes, a machine can now own money.) Owning the private keys to the address that created a contract is meaningless unless the contract has a rule that allows the creator to withdrawal the money. (And unlike accounts, contracts do not have a corresponding private key to the address of the contract.)

Can you please explain how you created the contracts? Were these standard contract wallets? If so, the money can likely be retrieved if you are the original owner. If not, there's not really much that can be done without more detail about the contract you created. (The source code of the contract will be needed.)

edit: I looked at your contract's code. It looks like it was the standard Ethereum contract wallet. If you have the private keys for the address that created it (0x4a5cfa400c63347c7c98d03c059b661d4f2edf20), you should be able to withdraw the funds from the contract. (Assuming you didn't put any rules on how the funds can be withdrawn.)

For those that are interested on how I figured out this was the standard Ethereum Wallet contract:

- Look here https://etherscan.io/address/0xdf2bf1aac908a97becb9a1fd43d3cbfda12379dc
- Switch to Contract Code
- Switch to opcodes view
- I saw it made reference to the standard Ethereum wallet contract at 0x273930d21e01ee25e4c219b63259d214872220a2.

It looks like you're already able to access the money from this contract wallet account. I see on the last line:

> Invocation Result: Balance change from 1,265.9750153799 Ether to
>   265.9750153799 Ether

edit2: I think I'm understand the purpose of this question now. (It was hard to understand what you were asking at first.) It sounds like you reinstalled something and are trying to get your wallet contracts back on the screen.

You'll need to re-add the contract wallet to your client.

- Click the Wallet Tab at the top
- Click Add Wallet Contract
- Click Import Wallet
- Paste this in the Wallet address: 0xdf2bf1aac908a97becb9a1fd43d3cbfda12379dc
- Click Create

You should now see your old wallet contract and have access to the funds again.

Comment: I first of all thks a lot for your help. So today i would like to test your solution but now in front of an other problem.... When i open my ethereal wallet... The wallet block on the 906,197 block. Can you tell me if you have a solution :-) thks

Comment: That is a very old block. Is it still syncing?

Comment: no my wallet stop  and don t want to sync

Comment: "and don t want to sync" I'm confused. Does that mean you'll never be selecting a correct answer to this question on StackExchange?

Comment: no :( can you help me?